# Using Ansible, need scripting help and how to check if application is already installed

Tags: bash, if-statement, ansible

I have a series of custom applications that need to be installed on several Ubuntu Linux servers. I am relatively new to Ansible (and yaml as well) so I am trying to understand the syntax of how to copy a file from the Ansible master host over to each of the clients, untar the tarball (separates into different directories) and then run each individual installer for each agent that needs to be installed: BelManage, AlertLogic and ESET.

I was thinking of something like this, but I don't know if it would work or if I am just going about it the wrong way:

```
---
 - name: Set variables needed for deployment
   hosts: nodeserver
   vars:
     - destdir: /home/ubuntu/apps

   tasks:
     - name: Copy bundle file with owner and permissions
       copy:
         src: /opt/apps/monitoring/linux-monitoring-apps.tar.gz
         dest: "{{destdir}}"
         owner: ubuntu
         group: ubuntu
         mode: '0644'

     - name: Untar application bundle
       ansible.builtin.shell: "cat linux-monitoring-apps.tar.gz | tar xzf -"
         args:
           chdir: "{{destdir}}"
           executable: /bin/bash
         become: yes
         become_user: root

     - name: Install ESET Application
       script: {{destdir}}/install-eset.sh

     - name: Install BelManage Application
       script: {{destdir}}/install-belmanage.sh

     - name: Install AI-Agent
       script: {{destdir}}/install-ai-agent.sh
```

In addition to running the scripts on each of the nodes, is there a way to do an if/else statement to check to see if the application is already installed on those nodes? If so, then just skip over the "script" kickoff and go to the next one?

Comment: I know it's more work but why not package your app for the distro you use and manage it that way? You'd have package manager (ie. `dpkg`) to handle that for you and your ansible role would only need to either set up repository and install or install from local package file

Comment: In general it seems the question only very slightly related to Ansible at all. How the applications BelManage, AlertLogic and ESET are usually managed? Do you have systemd service files for them? Are they checked and controlled in example via `systemctl status eset.service`? If not, could it be implement? How would you check if the application are installed if not using Ansible but in example CLI only?

Comment: At least for ESET it seems to be already covered by product documentation. https://help.eset.com/eeau/10/en-US/?mass_deployment.html

Comment: At the moment, all of the applications are installed manually. I am trying to find an automated solution so I won't have keep doing the manual steps. I am at the point now to see if Puppet or Ansible would be the better choice (not much of a developer) so just trying to see which one has the easier way of deploying the applications and can handle things like a if/else statement for checking to see if the application is already installed or not before attempting to install.